# Showing a pin in the center of Map View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to show a pin with location in the center of map view. I have coordinates, but it doesn't show in the center. Thanks!

Comment: Post your code then. Alexander just told you how to do it.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say Kampai just told you how to do it.

Comment: @DuncanC: This happened with me twice today :D. How ever I have added code for OP and waiting for his response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your `location` to map view center coordinates.

```
// Example location
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.79520324238053, -122.40283370018005);

// Drop a pin
MKPointAnnotation *startPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
startPin.coordinate = location;
startPin.title = @"Start";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:startPin];

[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:location];
```

Comment: I have misunderstood your question - see edits

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self mapView] setCenterCoordinate:location animated:YES];
```

where, location is type of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` which holds latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CLLocation *newLocation = locations.lastObject;
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate,1000.0, 1000.0);
    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    MKPointAnnotation *pointMap = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    pointMap.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    NSLog(@"didAddAnnotationViews");
    for (MKAnnotationView *view in views)
    {
        if ([[view annotation] isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([[view annotation] coordinate] , 1000.0, 1000.0);
            [mapView1 setRegion:region animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

}

```
- (MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation");
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }
        return nil;
}
```